# Setting Octet string to 0 in Java

Tags: java, snmp, net-snmp

i am using the following snmp set command to sent zero values into a hardware.

```
snmpset -v 3 -u <Username> -a SHA -A "password" -x AES -X "password" -l AuthPriv udp6:[<ipv6>%bond0] <oid> x 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

There are 1024 zeros, now i want to perform the same operation using the code.

But how will i get an octect string with the give values.

I tried using:

```
final List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(0);
final OctetString externalVlanIdsBitMapOctetString = BitMapUtils.createLeftBitmap(list);
```

But i am get snmpset fails with errorCode = 5.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether byte 0, or byte for char '0'. The latter version I commented out.

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
//Arrays.fill(bytes, (byte) '0');
final OctetString externalVlanIdsBitMapOctetString = new OctetString(bytes);
```

Comment: My intention is not to create just 1024 zeros. What i perform an snmpset i give Hexadecimal with 1024 zeros. <oid> x -> this x represents hexadecimal (i am not 100% sure). So i need to generate an Octet string for the corresponding 1024 zeros in hexadecimal. I hope you got my requirement.

Comment: I already guessed something like that. See @zhh; `zeros.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to create a string with 1024 zeros:

```
Sring zeros = String.format("%01024d", 0);
```